# Conditional Tags for specific category of custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags

How would I show a sidebar only if the post (a custom post type) belongs to a specific category of that custom post type?

I was looking for something like:

```
if ( is_singular( 'my_custom_post_type' ) && in_category( 'my_custom_post_type_category' ) )
```

but `in_category` doesn't seem to work. I tried with the category ID too, but no luck.

The theme uses the name `class_category` as the main category for this custom post type.

Comment: [`has_term( $term, $taxonomy, $post )`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) which accepts a `term_name`, `term_id`, or `slug` to test again. You'll need to pass the `post_id` too, something like this:

```
global $post;

if( isset( $post ) && is_singular( 'my_custom_post_type' ) && has_term( 'my_custom_post_type_category', 'my_custom_taxonomy', $post->ID ) ) {
    // Code Goes Here...
}
```

You *may* also be able to use [`has_category()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_category) which work very similar but if I were a betting man I'd bet that that function would only work for the built-in Post Categories but still worth mentioning.